# why is that filter FIR not IIR

Tags: filters, infinite-impulse-response, finite-impulse-response

[image]

how is this filter an fir filter should not  it be an iir because of the y[n-1 ] term

Comment: Have you tried calculating the filter's impulse response, to see if it's finite?

Comment: I did answer the exact same question a few years ago. If a filter is recursive (previous values of `y[n-k]` are being used), it doesn't necessarily imply that the impulse response is infinite. You must calculate the IR first.